# Recursively sorting an array of Strings without an auxiliary parameter

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

One of my professor's assignments is proving particularly tricky for me. I have to write a method with the following header:

```
public static void sort(String[] a)
```

The method should sort the array a in increasing order (not sure if that means "increasing order of string length", but that's what I'm assuming).

The catch: I'm not allowed to change the method header in any way, I'm not allowed to use either merge sort or quick sort, and I'm not allowed to use any extraneous packages/libraries.

Merge sort and quick sort being disallowed isn't that big a deal for me as I'm not very fond of either, but I'm finding it hard seeing how to do this without passing some auxiliary parameter (to store an index position for the array) that would get used in recursive invocations.

This is what I came up with after a few hours of frustration and basically spinning my wheels:

```
public static void sort(String[] a)
{

    String temp;

    // Note that we use a.length - 1 in the loop condition
    // to account for the fact that we will be checking the value of the 
    // element at the current index against the value of the element at the NEXT index.
    // Since array indices are zero-based, iterating from 0 to a.length would result
    // in an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when we index = 7, since the
    // base case would check a[7] against a[8], the latter of which does not exist

    for (int index = 0; index < a.length - 1; index++)
    {
        if (a[index].length() < a[index + 1].length())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = a[index + 1];
            a[index + 1] = a[index];
            a[index] = temp;

            // Recursive call to the sort method
            sort(a);
        }
    }
}
```

The basic idea was to check each element "multiple times" with the for loops so as to encourage each element getting into its "proper place" (in the "increasing order" sense). I doubt it's right, though I haven't tested it (professor hasn't uploaded a driver for this assignment yet).

If not, could someone maybe point me in the right direction? There don't seem to be any methods in either the Array or String class that would be useful here. I don't even see a use for recursion here; wouldn't it be useless if I'm just passing the method the same array over and over again?

Comment: Just implement bubble sort?

Comment: If the assignment is to use recursion, then maybe you could break the original array in smaller arrays and pass them to the method for recursion, that way you won't need additional parameters. If the assignment is not about recursion, follow Andy's advice: implement the classic bubble sort

Comment: does it have to be recursively?

Comment: Side note: typically, sorting `String`s is done _lexicographically_ and not by length; you should clarify ths with a professor

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit inefficient because it involves creation of new arrays and copying, but it matches the requirements that recursion must be used with the provided method signature.  It also satisfies the requirement that merge sort and quick sort must not be used.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RecursiveInsertionSort {
    public static void sort(String[] a)
    {
        if (a.length==1) {
            return;
        }
        // Copy array from 1..length-1 into new array rest
        String rest [] = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);
        // sort rest
        sort(rest);
        // insert a[0] into rest and store the result in a
        insert(a,rest);
    }

    // insert a[0] into sort and store result in a
    private static void insert(String [] a, String [] sorted) {
        int i;
        String saveFirst = a[0];

        // Find index 'i' where such that sorted[i] > a[0]
        for (i=0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            if (saveFirst.compareTo(sorted[i])<0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        // Copy elements less than a[0] from sorted to a
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++) {
            a[j] = sorted[j];
        }
        // insert a[0]
        a[i] = saveFirst;
        // copy elements greater than a[0] from sorted to a

        for (int j=i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
            a[j] = sorted[j-1];
        }

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String [] testData = {"Apples", "Oranges", "Cranberries", "Guava" };
        sort(testData);
        for (String s: testData) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an (in-place) [selection sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort):

- for each element of the array, first to last

  - iterate over the elements from the current element to the last, finding the smallest (which could be the current element)
  - swap the smallest one with the current one

Or an (in-place) [insertion sort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort):

- for each element of the array, first to last

  - shift previous elements to the right until the current element is less than the element just shifted and put the current element in the gap just created

The time complexity for both is O(n<sup>2</sup>), but the space complexity is O(1).

The problem doesn't say it has to be recursive.

Comment: I believe that is a selection sort, not an insertion sort.

Comment: @david quite so. I've edited to include both algorithm, with wiki links, for good measure.